# How to insert table values from one database to another database?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, integration, append

I want a query to insert records from one table to another table in a different database if the destination table already exists, it should append the records at the end of the table.

Answer (score 230):

How about this:

```
USE TargetDatabase
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.TargetTable(field1, field2, field3)
   SELECT field1, field2, field3
     FROM SourceDatabase.dbo.SourceTable
     WHERE (some condition)
```

Comment: 10 years later...still much appreciated.

Comment: First dbo stands for TargetDatabase

Comment: I had to use "DatabaseName.dbo.TableName"

Answer (score 38):

**How to insert table values from one server/database to another database?**

1 Creating Linked Servers {if needs} (SQL server 2008 R2 - 2012)
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx#SSMSProcedure

2 configure the linked server to use Credentials
a) http://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms189811(v=sql.105).aspx

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'NAMEOFLINKEDSERVER', 'false', null, 'REMOTEUSERNAME', 'REMOTEUSERPASSWORD'
```

-- CHECK SERVERS

```
SELECT * FROM sys.servers
```

-- TEST LINKED SERVERS

```
EXEC sp_testlinkedserver N'NAMEOFLINKEDSERVER'
```

---

INSERT INTO NEW LOCAL TABLE

```
SELECT * INTO NEWTABLE
FROM [LINKEDSERVER\INSTANCE].remoteDATABASE.remoteSCHEMA.remoteTABLE
```

OR

INSERT AS NEW VALUES IN REMOTE TABLE

```
INSERT
INTO    [LINKEDSERVER\INSTANCE].remoteDATABASE.remoteSCHEMA.remoteTABLE
SELECT  *
FROM    localTABLE
```

INSERT AS NEW LOCAL TABLE VALUES

```
INSERT
INTO    localTABLE
SELECT  *
FROM    [LINKEDSERVER\INSTANCE].remoteDATABASE.remoteSCHEMA.remoteTABLE
```

Answer (score 10):

```
    --Code for same server
USE [mydb1]
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.mytable1 (
    column1
    ,column2
    ,column3
    ,column4
    )
SELECT column1
    ,column2
    ,column3
    ,column4
FROM [mydb2].dbo.mytable2 --WHERE any condition

/*
steps-
    1-  [mydb1] means our opend connection database 
    2-  mytable1 the table in mydb1 database where we want insert record
    3-  mydb2 another database.
    4-  mytable2 is database table where u fetch record from it. 
*/

--Code for different server
        USE [mydb1]

    SELECT *
    INTO mytable1
    FROM OPENDATASOURCE (
            'SQLNCLI'
            ,'Data Source=XXX.XX.XX.XXX;Initial Catalog=mydb2;User ID=XXX;Password=XXXX'
            ).[mydb2].dbo.mytable2

        /*  steps - 
            1-  [mydb1] means our opend connection database 
            2-  mytable1 means create copy table in mydb1 database where we want 
                insert record
            3-  XXX.XX.XX.XXX - another server name.
            4-  mydb2 another server database.
            5-  write User id and Password of another server credential
            6-  mytable2 is another server table where u fetch record from it. */
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's a quick and easy method:

```
CREATE TABLE database1.employees
AS
SELECT * FROM database2.employees;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try

```
Insert into your_table_in_db1 select * from your_table_in_db2@db2SID
```

db2SID is the sid of other DB. It will be present in tnsnames.ora file

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT
INTO    remotedblink.remotedatabase.remoteschema.remotetable
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
```

There is no such thing as "the end of the table" in relational databases.

Comment: This is not a good choice, because it works much slower than inserting into local database where data in select is fetched from remote DB.

Answer (score 1):

Just Do it.....

( It will create same table structure as from table as to table with same data )

```
 create table toDatabaseName.toTableName as select * from fromDatabaseName.fromTableName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Mostly we need this type of query in migration script

```
INSERT INTO  db1.table1(col1,col2,col3,col4)
SELECT col5,col6,col7,col8
  FROM db1.table2
```

In this query column count must be same in both table

Answer (score 0):

If both the tables have the same schema then use this query:
**insert into database_name.table_name select * from new_database_name.new_table_name where='condition'**

Replace database_name with the name of your 1st database and table_name with the name of table you want to copy from
also replace new_database_name with the name of your other database where you wanna copy and new_table_name is the name of the table.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server, you can use tool Import Data from another Database, It's easier to configuration mapping columns.