# Insert in to a table which is filtered by a specific account number

Tags: sql

I have tried many times but i could not find the proper answer again i am asking same questing,

- 1 query

  (select * From acct_db2016.dbo.acct_tran where trc_acno='12008001')if i search like this i am getting 10 rows,
- 2 query

  (select * From acct_db.dbo.acct_tran where trc_acno='12008001')i am getting 4 rows
  so i want to insert to 1st query data base to 2nd query data base
  so the answer rows will be 14

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking for. What was the exact problem and the meaning of some of the variables you're using?

Comment: What SQL RDBMS are you trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

If you're inserting new values into the table, then you will use:

```
INSERT INTO ...
VALUES/SELECT...
```

If you're modifying data that already exists in the table, you will use:

```
UPDATE [Table]
SET [column] = [column]
WHERE condition
```

Comment: insert into a database specific table (but should be inserted where trc_acno 0000) from another database specific  table(acct_tran) which is filtered by using where clause (trc_ac no0000)

Comment: See [this former post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502269/how-to-insert-table-values-from-one-database-to-another-database)

Comment: please check this sir