# Import or Merge? Combining data

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two MDB databases that I'm bringing into MySQL via phpMyAdmin, one was internal and one from my customer.  Both DB's have the same structure and similar data.

I want to take the data from the ACCOUNTS table, AuditorCode column from my internal DB and insert it into the customer DB where the AcctDB = A and the AcctNo field match. In this first DB merge, I'm looking at 88 records that I want to update out of 4,000.

I've tried merges within phpMyAdmin and I've tried via uploading CSV and SQL files to no avail.  Could use some help on both the best method and how to use phpMyAdmin for this.

Comment: sorry, but stackoverflow is for coding questions.

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  I've been trying to use SQL to merge the data unsuccessfully.

Comment: A similar problem was here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502269/how-to-insert-table-values-from-one-database-to-another-database

Comment: That thread makes sense for SQL Server, but in phpMyAdmin I can't get the right syntax.