# How to Update different database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, localhost

How to Update data from database "testing" to "testing2" both have the same column.

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GX4GJ.png)

Comment: Does this help you out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502269/how-to-insert-table-values-from-one-database-to-another-database

Comment: What have you tried so far? That should be well documented

Comment: @NicoHaase that's only for `testing` but `testing2` don't have the data like `testing`.

Comment: Still, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

just use databasename.tablename.column for updating one database to different database table

example

```
    update testing.tbl_customer 
inner join testing2.tbl_customer
on testing.tbl_customer.CustomerID=testing2.tbl_customer.CustomerID

set testing.tbl_customer.CustomerName=testing2.tbl_customer.CustomerName
```

if you want to update more column just use coma and put column name in set cluase

Comment: I don't understand `RA.Sales` `tblAccounts` `tblSalesRepsAccountLink` `AccountCode` where did you get that?

Comment: @Noob that is alis of 2nd dabatabase and its table name, can you please share your database name and table name so that i can make example by using yours

Comment: just click sample image

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE testing2.tbl_customer c1
INNER JOIN testing.tbl_customer c2 ON c1.CustomerID = c2.CustomerID 
SET c1.CustomerName = c2.CustomerName,
    c1.Address = c2.Address, 
    c1.City = c2.City, 
    c1.PostalCode = c2.PostalCode, 
    c1.Country = c2.Country
```

Comment: is there any difference between first ans and yours ?