# Use procedure of one database and save data into another database table using C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have many databases and the database is dynamically changed by input in connection string. But I have procedure in one database suppose named 'DB1' and want to insert data into another database named 'DB2'.

I can't make another connection string for inserting purpose, because I don't know about databases.

My code:

```
SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connString"].ConnectionString);

conn1.Open();

SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand();
cmd3.Connection = conn1;
cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd3.CommandText = "storedProcedure";

cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col0", string.IsNullOrEmpty(index[0].ToString()) ? (object)DBNull.Value : index[0].ToString());    
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col1", string.IsNullOrEmpty(index[1].ToString()) ? (object)DBNull.Value : index[1].ToString());
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col2", string.IsNullOrEmpty(index[2].ToString()) ? (object)DBNull.Value : index[2].ToString());
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col3", string.IsNullOrEmpty(index[3].ToString()) ? (object)DBNull.Value : index[3].ToString());

cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I am using two connection strings, one for use the procedure and second for insert data into a specific database. I want insert data into 2nd connection string named connString1. But I don't know how can I do this.

My connection string:

```
<add name="connString" 
     connectionString="Data Source=DBSERVER-PC\SQL2012;Database=DB1;User ID=sa;Password=a "
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

<add name="connString1" 
     connectionString="Data Source=DBSERVER-PC\SQL2012;Database=DB2;User ID=sa;Password=a "
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Any idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Any reason you can't deploy the stored procedure into both databases?

Comment: I have Db1 that have stored procedure but i want to insert data into another database. So we can use one connectionstring at a time, right? then how can i do?

Comment: Question not clear. Is the stored procedure for data retrieval or for inserting the data?

Comment: stored procedure is for inserting data. Procedure is in database1 and want to insert data into another database2's table.

Comment: If the databases are in the same server, have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502269/how-to-insert-table-values-from-one-database-to-another-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose You have a Table in `(Database) DB1` called FROM `dbo.item`

```
--------------------
item_id | base_price
--------------------
   1    |   10.5

   2    |   6.5
```

You want this `table insert into another (Database) DB2`  called `[dbo].[Testitem]`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Sp_InsertData
(
@DBNAME VARCHAR(100) = NULL     
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX)       
SET @str='INSERT INTO ' + @DBNAME + '.dbo.Testitem(item_id, base_price) select item_id, base_price from dbo.item '
exec (@str)

END
```

**Testing Script For Execute SP**

```
EXEC dbo.Sp_InsertData
@DBNAME='DB2'
```

**Note:-** You have pass `Database(DB2)` name From Code behind as `@Paramter in DB1`
using `web.config`.....